# Extension method for strongly typed property access

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods, expression, strong-typing

I have the following class hierarchy

```
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class TestChild : Test
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

I **can't** change the Test class. I want to write following extension method like this:

```
static class TestExtensions
{
    public static string Property<TModel, TProperty>(this Test test, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return property.ToString();
    }
}
```

To be able to use it in the following way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestChild t = new TestChild();
        string s = t.Property(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

But now compiler says

> The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.TestExtensions.Property(ConsoleApplication1.Test, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I want to have something like mvc Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) method. 
Is it possible to write extension to be used as shown in the `Main` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static class TestExtensions
{
    public static string Property<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel test, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return property.ToString();
    }
}
```

The compiler should be able to infer the first argument...

Comment: I missed this the first time :(

Comment: Also, I don't think that property.ToString() is the right thing to be doing there.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the generic arguments for the call, that's all:

```
string s = t.Property<TestChild, string>(x => x.Name);
```

EDIT:

My fault.  I missed the real problem:

```
public static string Property<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
{
    return property.ToString();
}
```

This should make it so you can omit the generic arguments. I assume you are also processing real code in this method to get the property name?  If not, you may actually want this:

```
public static string Property<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
{
    var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Comment: That is the case. Is is possible to omit them? Like asp.net mvc extension methods Html.TextBoxFor?

Comment: arg +1 same thing I just wrote :)

Comment: Thanks, toString was just to get started :)